# how to indent code when highlighting use highlight.js

Tags: javascript, highlight.js

I'm using highlight.js to highlight my MySQL Create table DDL code.

but i find the code was changed to single line,  after highlight.js formatting it.

so, is there some config on highlight.js to indent the code to pretty formatted  style ?

[image: before]
[image: after using highlight.js]

Comment: I have the same issue. After calling hljs.highlightAll() function, my code re-formats into a single line.

Answer (score 0):

`<pre>` tags should work here, in addition to the `<code>` tags I assume you're already using:

```js
hljs.highlightAll();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.6.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

<pre><code class="language-sql">create_table test_66(
  id int(10) auto_increment primary key,
  user_id int(10) not null
) engine=innodb charset=utf8;</code></pre>
```